# PictureBox with overriden OnPaint method in C#

Tags: c#, picturebox, onpaint

I would like to paint some small pictures in PictureBox (4 x 32px images in a row) so should i override OnPaint method or i need to make my new component that extends PictureBox?
I tried this, which worked in Java, but not here:

```
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        {
            protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
            {
               // If there is an image and it has a location, 
               // paint it when the Form is repainted.
                Graphics g = e.Graphics;

                // Draw a string on the PictureBox.
                g.DrawString("Test, is that working?",
                new Font("Arial", 10), System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, new Point(30, 30));
             }
        }
```

Full code of InitializeComponent method:

```
   private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Tools));
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        {
            protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
            {
               // If there is an image and it has a location, 
               // paint it when the Form is repainted.
                Graphics g = e.Graphics;

                // Draw a string on the PictureBox.
                g.DrawString("Test, is that working?",
                new Font("Arial", 10), System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, new Point(30, 30));
             }
        }
        this.vscrollb = new System.Windows.Forms.VScrollBar();
        this.vScrollBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.VScrollBar();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Left;
        this.pictureBox1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("pictureBox1.Image")));
        this.pictureBox1.InitialImage = null;
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(264, 262);
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint);
        // 
        // vscrollb
        // 
        this.vscrollb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.vscrollb.Name = "vscrollb";
        this.vscrollb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 80);
        this.vscrollb.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // vScrollBar1
        // 
        this.vScrollBar1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right;
        this.vScrollBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(267, 0);
        this.vScrollBar1.Name = "vScrollBar1";
        this.vScrollBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(17, 262);
        this.vScrollBar1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.vScrollBar1.Scroll += new System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventHandler(this.HandleScroll);
        // 
        // Tools
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.vScrollBar1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.Name = "Tools";
        this.Text = "Tools";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
```

Comment: This code works fine, what's the issue?

Comment: I've added this to InitializeComponent method. This is full code:

Comment: @PiotrŁużecki: DO NOT add anything to the 'InitializeComponent' as this method will be overwritten by the Designer everytime it changes something. You can add it "after" 'InitializeComponent' is called in the constructor.

Comment: I'm trying to do this as you said, but i have compilation error near first bracket: Invalid initializer member declarator. I can't override method there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This just isn't valid C# code.  Overriding a virtual method like OnPaint() is fine but you can only do so in a class that's derived from PictureBox.  Which works well, after you compile you'll get the new control automatically added to the toolbox so you can put it on a form.

This is however not necessary.  You can simply implement the Paint event for the control.  You already did, you named it pictureBox1_Paint().  Just move your code there.

Other important pointers: never edit InitializeComponent().  It is auto-generated by the designer.  As soon as you modify the design of the form, you'll lose any code you wrote there.  It is also a really good way to make the form un-designable, triggering an exception when the form is loaded by the designer.  And if you do override OnPaint() then it is important that you call base.OnPaint().  So that the normal PictureBox plumbing continues to work.  Including painting the Image and raising the Paint event.  Be sure to at least follow a tutorial or read a book about Winforms programming, there will be a lot of trial and mostly error if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to inherit from `PictureBox` and add your logic there. So you don't have to add logic to a place where it doesn't belong (parent control).

```
public class SpecialPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // if you want to execute the original PaintBox logic before you execute your own code, use the next line of code.
        base.OnPaint(e);

        // now do whatever you want

    }
}
```

You then can use the `SpecialPictureBox` wherever you want.

**Edit:** added `base.OnPaint` to code example

Comment: So i can't do this without making new class? Do i have to call some events like OnPaint or something else? Can i add this to Toolbox?

Comment: You could do it without making a new class, but I would not recommend it as it is a typical OOP principal to inherit to add special functionalities. The behavior of you new class is exactly the same as it was before except the new implementation of the OnPaint' method. After you compile your project the new control will be available within the toolbox.

Comment: One more thing: If you override the OnPaint method, the PictureBox will not paint a picture as it was doing before, because you overrode the logic. If you want the pb to execute its own logic before you add yours, you have to execute base.OnPaint(e) as the first call in your overridden method.

Comment: I can use `this.Image` in the SpecialPictureBox yet when I use the specialPictureBox in visulstudio form designer, it throw an error meaning `this` is NULL...