# How to know when a control is fully visible?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a time-sensitive C# Windows Forms application. I need to turn the visibility of a picture box on and off. When I turn it on, I would like to know the exact time in which the image became fully visible. Not just the event of changing the "Visible" property, but the event in which the last pixel of the image was drawn on the screen when the image becomes visible. Is there an event or callback that signals this?

Comment: About the only time when contents would not be rendered immediately (following an update) was if the source (ie. the image to render) wasn't already loaded.. so perhaps a better question might be, "How do I know when a Picture Box finished loading an image?"

Comment: With that query in google, one can find links to documentation such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.onloadcompleted?view=net-5.0 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525407/how-do-i-know-when-an-image-is-loaded-in-picturebox (mentions needing to use LoadAsync).

Comment: You may be able to create a custom Derived PictureBox and replace [OnPaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox.onpaint) where you will call [base](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,b54dc306080a5d6f,references) and get the time right after, or do whatever you want before and after (to get for example the time used to repaint completely).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PictureBox with overriden OnPaint method in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871448/picturebox-with-overriden-onpaint-method-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The image is already loaded in the PictureBox. It is loaded as the BackgroundImage property of the control in Visual Studio. The only thing I do is to turn the Visible property to true/false when I want to show it or hide it. Does this mean that if a line of code executes "pictureBox.Visible = true", the next line will execute after the image is fully drawn?

Comment: "*Does this mean that if a line of code executes "pictureBox.Visible = true", the next line will execute after the image is fully drawn?*" => Yes because all UI operations are single threaded in WinForms. So setting visible to true from false tells the control to draw itself entirely, and after that the next statement *in your code* is executed, fully painted before. This is why the design of huge user interface, having for example hundreds or thousands of controls, lags, even on modern and power computers, from few seconds to minutes. Example: a panel with 1000 TextBox can take 5-15s or more.

Comment: Thank you, the last comment solves my question